# How to create very small JRE using jrecreate in ejdk for windows 10?

Tags: java

I want to ship my java application (command line tool) along with a small jre. I tried a lot using *jrecreate* options of *ejdk* but, I am unable to create jre for windows 10. Please help me in this regard. I referred the following links. It is always creating for linux. How to do it for Windows ?

I used the the following command:

```
jrecreate.bat --profile compact2 --dest compact2-client --vm all
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/jtc/introducing-the-ejdk

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/index.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/installing.htm

Comment: I am using JDK 8. I know there is a way to modularize in JDK-9, but I do not want to migrate to Java 9. Oracle provides this feature, it provides only for linux, also it provides documentation for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

> You already know what you are going to package into your JRE. 
>   Like you have a list of dependencies or you have a jar file and you need to extract the dependencies and create a JRE with only those dependencies

If Java version is not of concern then you can stick to Java 9 and follow this post here.
https://medium.com/azulsystems/using-jlink-to-build-java-runtimes-for-non-modular-applications-9568c5e70ef4
I tried this a couple of weeks ago and it worked.
Regarding Win or Linux, it depends upon where you are running the jlink command

Answer (score -1):

I used the following command to get compacted jre with profile compact1 in MAC.

```
jrecreate.sh -d ./compact1-jre/ -p compact1
```

Comment: Hi @Hari, did you try in windows, from where did you download ejdk for windows 64 bit? If you hav any link, please post here.

Comment: You can download the executables from 'https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-embedded-java-se-downloads.html'. Once you extract the executable, you can see 'jrecreate.bat' file in bin directory. I am not tried on Windows, it may work.

Comment: Thnaks a lot @Hari. Let me check.

Comment: But I did not see ejdk for Windows